# Need help with Internet Explorer 9 Display problem

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

Please help me out I don't know why the website menu navigation doesn't display properly with IE9

It is work perfectly with IE8,IE7 and firefox but when I load it up on IE9. The wording on the navigation menu gone!

```
The website address is www.ii-s.com.au
```

I have no clue what's going on, can anybody kindly give me some suggestion!

Thanks so much in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is dat IE9 still has problems with Cufon, which you use to display the custom fonts.

Try this:
http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/fix-for-cufon-not-working-in-ie9beta/31932

Comment: Thanks for your help so much. Its working perfectly now by downloading the curfon.js file from the site you gave me.